# Limited number of paging to 10 "pages: 1 ... 10"

Tags: pagination, limit

How to limit the function of paging down to stop at number 10?
Eg: pages: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

```
function kriesi_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{  
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class='pagination'>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you mean to completely stop and #11 and up should be never linked and shown or to limit simultaneously shown pages to 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ($i=1; $i <= min($pages,10); $i++)
```

Comment: Perfect @Michael. It was probably easy enough for you, lol. I confess: I'm just a beginner in php.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
{
   if($i >= 11) break;

 if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
         }
}
```

Comment: Thank @AnupRaj. Unfortunately there appears to be a bug in that code, all disappeared number, and was only 11 (pages: 11).